# MySQL: How to get distinct name but also by state?

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

My Currect query is working, here is my current approach:

```
//loop through the defined fields & build query
foreach($searchFields as $searchField){
    // if the field is set and not empty
    if(isset($_POST[$searchField]) && $_POST[$searchField] != '') {
        // create a new condition while escaping the value inputed by the user (SQL Injection)
        $searchConditions[] = "`$searchField` LIKE '%" . $_POST[$searchField] . "%'";
    }
}

//build the query
//$getExperts_sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";
$getExperts_sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(*) as casecount FROM $tablename";

// if there are conditions defined
if(count($searchConditions) > 0) {
    // append the conditions
    $getExperts_sql .= " WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $searchConditions) ." GROUP BY first,last"; // you can change to 'OR', but I opt'd to apply the filters cumulative
}
```

As mentioned it is working.. (as it should).. but I need help getting a little more granular/specfic.

as it stands.. it -does- select only distinct/unique names... (which is what I need).. but I also need to add in another piece of data to be 'distinct' with   (if that makes sense)

Currently.. if I have duplciate names records.. it only returns 1.. but if they have a different state.. it doesnt take that into account.

example data structure:

John    Doe     CA

John    Doe     CA

John    Doe     CA

Jane    Doe     CA

Jane    Doe     CA

John    Doe     NY

John    Doe     NY

Jenny   Doe     WI

Billy   Bob PA

Billy   Bob PA

John    Doe WA

Peter   Paul    FL

Peter   Paul    FL

Peter   Paul    FL

Peter   Paul    FL

in my table..

I want it to return only 1 John Doe (for CA)... but also return John Doe NY (1 time), as well as John Doe WA (1 time)... well hes only in there one time.. but you get the idea :)

Right now, I will only get John Doe returned 1 time.. (must take the first one found in the table I believe)

Where as I am looking to get '3' John Does returned..

I guess I am looking ta distinct name & state? together?... but not sure how I can alter my current query to get there.

I cant use DISTINCT on just first/last name.. and I cant just use it on state either..

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: so just add 'state' to the group by params?  (seems to be working).. although I'm not clear if thats what you were suggesting with just a link and no context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If state is in your table, this will work.  Simply add state to your `Group By` statement.

```
$getExperts_sql .= " WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $searchConditions) ." GROUP BY first,last, state"; // you can change to 'OR', but I opt'd to apply the filters cumulative
```

Comment: While I do appreciate the link, there was no context for it.

What Tom posted was exactly what I did:

    `GROUP BY first,last,state`